# Вопрос по css. Почему такой результат

Tags: css

Есть такой код

```css
UL LI UL {
  color: green;
}
UL UL {
  color: red;
}
LI SPAN {
  color: blue;
}
LI LI {
  color: fuchsia;
}
UL SPAN {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Первый</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Второй</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>Третий</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

И к нему вопрос - Какой цвет будет у текста списка в следующем коде?
Я ожидал , что будет срабатывать `LI SPAN { color: blue; }` так как это более конкретный указатель. Но срабатывает `UL SPAN { color: orange; }`. В комментариях я нашел такую фразу, что `UL SPAN { color: orange; }` находится в конце списка - поэтому и срабатывает. Но я добавил в конец списка `LI SPAN { color: blue; }`, и все равно срабатывает цвет орандж. После чего я из списка вообще удалил `UL SPAN { color: orange; }` ожидая что в таком случае сработает `LI LI { color: fuchsia; }`. Ведь он соответсвует всем условиям - и находится в конце списка, и li вложен  li, но срабатывает blue , что меня вообще запутало. Какой тут алгоритм выбора стиля получается ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все смешалось в кучу.

Вы смотрите стиль, который применяется к `span`, соответственно нужно рассматривать описанные стили по специфичности к `span`.

[Свойство color](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-color) наследуется, следовательно, если оно не задано у элемента, то будут проверяться родители у которых оно задано.

Если рассмотреть по специфичности:
LI SPAN {
  color: blue;
}
UL SPAN {
  color: orange;
}

```css
UL LI UL {
  color: green;
}
UL UL {
  color: red;
}
LI SPAN {
  color: blue;
}
LI LI {
  color: fuchsia;
}
UL SPAN {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Первый</span></li>
      <li><span>Второй</span></li>
      <li><span>Третий</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

по отношению к элементу `span` данные селекторы равнозначны, проверяется только один элемент в который вложен span, поэтому применяется тот, который описан позже.
В данном случае это `UL SPAN` и показывается оранжевым цветом.

Если вставить `LI SPAN` ниже - то применится он

```css
UL LI UL {
  color: green;
}
UL UL {
  color: red;
}
LI LI {
  color: fuchsia;
}
UL SPAN {
  color: orange;
}
LI SPAN {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Первый</span></li>
      <li><span>Второй</span></li>
      <li><span>Третий</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Далее, если убрать `UL SPAN`

```
UL LI UL {
  color: green;
}
UL UL {
  color: red;
}
LI SPAN {
  color: blue;
}
LI LI {
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

Получаем `LI SPAN`, который устанавливает значение `color` для `span`, и `LI LI` - который устанавливает значение `color` для родителя, и следовательно применяется если не установлено для span.

Таким образом `LI SPAN` более специфичный селектор для span, и цвет выставляется blue

```css
UL LI UL {
  color: green;
}
UL UL {
  color: red;
}
LI SPAN {
  color: blue;
}
LI LI {
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Первый</span></li>
      <li><span>Второй</span></li>
      <li><span>Третий</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```